# Search/Copy/Insert VBA Macro causing multiple different crashes in Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I'm experiencing a strange issue occurring with my VBA Macros in Excel. Background is, I'm creating a template for Labour Logs to log hours that employees are on site. There is a main sheet where all the data is entered "Labour Log" and then 8 sheets, one for each of the days of the week and a Holidays sheet. There is a hidden sheet where my dynamic list and static lists are held.

The macros that are causing issues are the ones on the sheets for the days of the week. What they are doing is, searching the Labour Logs sheet for any cell with that day of the week in column B, then inserting that line on row 8 of the day sheet. This loops until all instances are entered. Example of Monday below.

```
Private Sub PullMondayData_Click()
Dim dc As Range
    With Sheets("Labour Log") 'Reference to Labour Log Sheet
        For Each dc In Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange)
            If dc.Value2 = "Monday" Then 'Search/Filter B:B for Monday
                dc.Resize(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy 'Copy the row
                Sheets("Monday").Rows(8).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Insert in Row 8, shifting down
            End If
        Next

    End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Remove copy mode
End Sub
```

This usually works fine for Monday. I can usually hit that one multiple times without issue.

When I go back to the Labour Log sheet and change the day to any other day, I start getting errors on those sheets when hitting the macro. The macro codes is exactly the same, but with the relevant day entered in the correct spots.

The first error I usually get is:

[image]

Going to debug says error with this line:

[image]

I then stop the macro and run it again, getting the following error:

[image]

Debugging it gives this line:

[image]

After that, the only way I can close the Excel sheet is to end the process form the Task Manager, the rest of the program is locked.

From time to time, I also get a crash, and the output is this:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: EXCEL.EXE
  Application Version:  16.0.6868.2060
  Application Timestamp:    5723a711
  Fault Module Name:    mso20win32client.dll
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   57222bc3
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0008c78d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    4105

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033
  skulcid:  1033
```

I've searched online for various answers, but they don't seem to work. I've tried the following:

- Clearing the Excel folder in C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel
- Cleaning the Registry
- Changning the set printer (long shot, but saw a few people say it worked)
- Running another day before Monday
- Running Windows Update
- Moving `Application.CutCopyMode = False` within the If loop

My knowledge of VBA isn't great and a lot of this code was taken from searches and altered to suit my purpose, but I don't understand why it is working for the Monday sheet, but crashes on all others.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

too little info to actually track that error down

but, assuming you're using a Userform with many buttons to click and have proper day processed, I'd propose you some code that can possibly help you keep things cleaner and, therefore, less prone to errors

- set your buttons `caption` property as per the relevant day

  so you'll have

  - `PullMondayData` button showing "Monday" caption on it
  - `PullTuesdayData` button showing "Tuesday" caption on it
  - and so on
- have all your `Pull`*`day`*`button` "Click" event handlers code just like follows:

  ```
  Private Sub PullMondayData_Click()
     PullDayData (Me.ActiveControl.Caption)
  End Sub

  Private Sub PullTuesdayData_Click()
     PullDayData (Me.ActiveControl.Caption)
  End Sub
  ```

  and so on
- add the following sub to your Userform code pane

  ```
  Private Sub PullDayData(thisDay As String)
     Dim dc As Range

     With Sheets("Labour Log") 'Reference to Labour Log Sheet
         For Each dc In Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange)
             If dc.Value2 = thisDay Then 'Search/Filter B:B for Monday
                 With Sheets(thisDay).Rows(8)
                     .Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Insert in Row 8, shifting down
                     .Value = dc.Resize(1, 1).EntireRow.Value
                 End With
             End If
         Next    
     End With
  End Sub
  ```

all what above can still greatly improved, but it'll give you at least the following benefits:

- write much less code

  and thus both make much less effort in maintaining it and possibly have many few errors!
- not make use of copy/paste methods to both not passing through clipboard and be faster

For further effective improvements I'd suggest you the following steps:

- use [AutoFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884(v=office.15).aspx)  and [SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) methods of `Range` object to improve both control and efficency
- use classes

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with user3598756 that this isn't enough to give an answer with certainty, I do have some additional things to try:

1. I've had much better results using `.CurrentRegion`, than `.UsedRange` to get the area of data. There are exceptions, but if you have headers that can't be blank and at least one column with no blanks, it works flawlessly.
2. When you have more than one thing on a line causing an error, breaking it out will give you better info about crashes, so change: `dc.Resize(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy` into two statements: `dc.Resize(1,1)` and `dc.EntireRow.Copy`.
3. COM objects, and Range objects like .Rows(x) in particular, are tricky beasts. This seems to be worse in C# addons than VBA macros, but I've often seen them not update as expected when you do something to major their contents. The work around is the general case of the specific case I gave in point 2: one dot good, two dots bad. For example instead of calling `Sheets("Monday").Rows(8).Insert` try something like:

---

```
   Dim MondaySheetRow as Range
   MondaySheetRow = Sheets("Monday").Rows(8)
   MondaySheetRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

4. Lastly I've made a habit of not updating sheets that aren't active. Instead I activate the sheet I'm going to make changes to, make the changes, then return to the originally active sheet. This mimics the way a user would manually make the changes which also helps visually show where the macro went in the calls leading up to an error.